# Extending the domain of the "greatest common divisor" function.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

In the seventeenth century the famous mathematician [Leonhard Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) extends the concept of [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) $n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2\cdot 1$ of $\mathbb{N}$ to non-integer values. Euler setting $r!$, for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$, using what we know today as [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) $\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty  x^{t-1} e^{-x}\, dx$, as 
$$
r!=\Gamma(r+1)=\int_0^\infty  x^{r} e^{-x}\, dx.
$$
Something that seems intuitively impossible. Thus, for example we have 
$$
\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )! =\Gamma\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )= \sqrt{\pi} 
$$

This fact makes me believe that the question I ask below is not senseless. It is well known that we can look at the **greatest common divisor(gcd)** of two natural numbers as a function $\gcd:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{cll}
\gcd(a,a) = & a & \\
\gcd(a,b) = &\gcd(a - b,b),&  \mbox{if } a > b\\
\gcd(a,b) = &\gcd(a, b-a),& \mbox{if }   b > a
\end{array}
 $$

> **QUESTION.** Is there any reference on the extension function greatest common divisor $\mathrm{gcd}$ of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0)\}$? By extension I mean a continuous function for $a> 0$ and $b>0$ such that
>   such that
>   $$
> \begin{array}{cll}
> \gcd(a,a) = & a & \\
> \gcd(a,b) = &\gcd(a - b,b),&  \mbox{if } a > b\\
> \gcd(a,b) = &\gcd(a, b-a),& \mbox{if }   b > a
> \end{array}
> $$

The properties of the order in $\mathbb{R}$ make me discouraged to get a positive response. But I could not give a negative answer to my question.

Comment: I may be naive, but I expect not, since restricted to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, it is not even increasing in the first place.  I would expect that you could extend it to $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ however, stipulating that you take the smallest common denominator and then taking the gcd of the numerators.  What would it even mean for two real numbers to share a nonzero divisor?  The only function that seems to fit is $\overline{gcd}(x,y)=1$.  I would be interested to hear what other more well-versed people have to say about this.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the pointers. I corrected my little mistake.

Comment: When you say “By extension I mean a function $\gcd(x,y)$ for $x>0$ and $y>0$ is increasing,” what do you mean? The function $\gcd(m,n)$ is not increasing to begin with for integers $n$ as $m$ to begin with as one integer is fixed. $\gcd(2,n)$ alternates between $1$ and $2$ as $n$ increases. While it might not be interesting, you could define $\gcd(x,y)$ for real numbers $x$ and $y$ to be a weighted average of
$\gcd(\lfloor x\rfloor,\lfloor y\rfloor)$,$\gcd(\lceil x\rceil,\lfloor y\rfloor)$,$\gcd(\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil y\rceil)$, and $\gcd(\lceil x\rceil,\lceil y\rceil)$.

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks for the pointers. I corrected my little mistake. I meant for continuous $x>0$ and $y> 0$.

Comment: Well if there is then it doesn't have the "d" in it, right? (unless you have a way to define a *divisor* over $\mathbb{R}$).